# Netflix works on chrome but not chromium?

Tags: chrome

On my debian installation I installed chromium 39 and the latest version of libnss3, netflix failed to play. I tried on my ubuntu installation and it too failed. I tried installing chrome from the website and it WORKED. I looked at the version of chrome and chromium. They're both 39.0.2171.XY. AFAIK chrome 38+ works.

Why doesn't netflix work in chromium while chrome does? Is there a way I can have netflix run in chromium?

Answer (score 24):

It is because `chrome` packages the...

> Widevine Content Decryption Module - Version: 1.4.6.667
>
> Enables Widevine licenses for playback of HTML audio/video content. (version: 1.4.6.667)

...whereas `chromium` does not and in August 2014 Netflix switched to allowing HTML5 content by default. Visit:

> chrome://plugins

...to see a list.

You will need that plugin installed to `chromium` for it to work. You might also add the google talk plugin and pdf plugin while you're at it, but if you do so you pretty much just installed `chrome` as those are some of the primary differences.

In fact, though, until late summer 2015 you couldn't install that component singly to `chromium` - we can chalk that one up to another *(short-lived)* win for *Digital Restrictive Management,* I guess. With some serious downtime and expert hacking you might be able to compile your own package *(a `chromium` compile is no Sunday drive, by the way)* - but you might have to hack the plugin out of `chrome`.

Failing that, you can use the Ubuntu `chrome` ppa source, I suppose:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | 
sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | 
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
```

...should probably do the trick, I guess, if you're ok with using the closed-source `chrome` binary.

As of August 2015, though, you can [*now* install the Widevine module separately](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/33ed7q/chromium_from_extra_now_capable_of_netflix/) as the `chromium` maintainer has patched the source to accept its use. For example, on an Arch Linux system there is the [chromium-widevine AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chromium-widevine/) package. Have a look at its [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=chromium-widevine) script to see how it's done - it doesn't look very complicated. Essentially the `chrome...deb` debian package file is downloaded, from it are extracted only a few Widevine relevant files, their version numbers captured, and then these are copied into the relevant `chromium` installation paths.

There is also the [Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html) project which should enable you to use the Silverlight plugin *(via `wine`)* to watch Netflix video *(and so not the HTML5 method which works with `chrome`)* in `chromium`. It is a somewhat heavy-handed approach in my opinion, but it is a popular option.

Comment: Yep you're right those are some of the differences in my chrome and chromium browsers. How do I add the Widevine Content Decryption Module to chromium?

Comment: @acidzombie24 - well, in arch linux it can be done easily with a package in the aur. Surely there is an ubuntu ppa you might add into `apt`'s list to do the same. But... why? If it is about autoupdates then the newer versions of `chrome` will handle that on their own - and may have even already installed the sources to your sources list, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I rather have debian/ubuntu compile the binaries I use on my OS. I was thinking about using trisquel which is a gnu OS but their newest version is terrible and ubuntu/debian is better supported. I can't figure out how to install widevine. I tried visiting the website https://tools.google.com/dlpage/widevine but it says linux is not supported. Before that I tried a apt search for widevine and it found nothing. I have no clue how to install this

Comment: @acidzombie24 - I guess the arch linux aur packages I was thinking about don't include the widevine module either - only the pdf and pepperflash and the rest.

Comment: Anybody got know if it's possible to load the widevine linux plugin into firefox somehow? I assume the plugin architecture is entirely different ...

Comment: The `chrome-widevine` plugin didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Chromium has be recompiled to be able to load the binary widevine component, instructions are available on the chromium bug tracking this problem :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429452#c16

Answer (score 4):

We now have a working solution ! thanks to the great work of saiarcot895  and fabian.r )

You can use this PPA for Ubuntu/debian

https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta

Extract the libwidevinecdmadapter.so and libwidevinecdm.so from the /opt/google/chrome beta 43 directory ( we will package this later.)

And copy both files to /usr/lib/chromium-browser/

Launch chromium and you're done !

The great point is that saiarcot895 has enable VAAPI support  in these chromium builds so now you can watch SUPERHD netflix on low end Intel Soc like Baytrail ( you couldn't even with chrome ....)

Please confirm it works on your side.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Chromium is a Debian package and therefore Free Software, so it does not have any Digital Restrictive Management support, which Netflix requires.

Comment: I note that I have a down-vote. If you know any reason that this is not true then please leave a comment. Otherwise, I know that DRM makes you angry, but don't take your anger out on me.

Answer (score 3):

Arch Linux:

1. Install both chromium and google-chrome
2. Link to the Google Chrome library from Chromium: `ln -s /opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdm.so /usr/lib/chromium/libwidevinecdm.so`
3. Launch/restart `chromium` and enjoy