# Chromium - Enabling Widevine Content Decryption Module

Tags: chrome, qt, chromium-os

I am trying to enable Widevine inside Chromium in order to play video from source like Netflix.

Recompiling Chromium is not really an option since I use Qt new browser that uses Chromium. I'm trying to find a way to ship the plugin with my application, so that Chromium loads it by default.

Related post on this subject:

[Netflix works on chrome but not chromium?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172364/netflix-works-on-chrome-but-not-chromium/190747)

https://forum.qt.io/topic/52183/qwebengine-netflix-support/4

Comment: This [might have been fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50132) very recently for QtWebEngine 5.7. You could wait for the 5.7 beta release to test it, or you could download their 5.7 git branch and compile it if you don't want to wait to find out.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429452, you really need to rebuild Chromium to be able to use the CDM.

Comment: I am using the Qt framework that use Chromium. In the last version, they have added pepper flash so maybe it will work. Rebuilding is not possible, Thanks

Comment: The CDM is not Flash, so: no.