# How to watch discovery.com videos on Linux?

Tags: video, firefox, chrome, browser, streaming

I can't get Discovery videos to play at all in Linux. For example, in Chromium version 47.0.2526.106:

1. Run `chromium --incognito https://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/final-season-sneak-peek/`
2. Verify that **the video window is grey**.
3. Click on the grey shield icon in the URL field.
4. Verify that a message pops up saying **“This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources.”**
5. Press "Load unsafe scripts".
6. Verify that the video window first displays **“[Name of video] is currently unavailable.”**
7. Verify that the video window then changes to say **“No video has been loaded. Error Code: PLAYER_ERR_NO_SRC”**.

In Firefox 43.0.1:

1. Run `firefox -no-remote --safe-mode https://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/final-season-sneak-peek/`
2. Verify that after the page finishes loading **the video window stays black.**

I have installed the Flash plugin:

```
$ pacman --sync --search flashplugin
extra/flashplugin 11.2.202.559-1 [installed]
    Adobe Flash Player
multilib/lib32-flashplugin 11.2.202.559-1
    Adobe Flash Player for 32-bit Mozilla-based browsers
```

Is there any way to fix this? I'd use `youtube-dl` as a workaround, but [right now discovery.com download is failing](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/8065).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to hear that, but there is a m3u8 list that you can maybe use with wget: http://discidevflash-f.akamaihd.net/i/digmed/dsc/20151204/149218.071.01.197_20151204_101536-,400k,110k,200k,600k,800k,1500k,3500k,5000k,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8

Comment: That's really interesting @JohannesM! I had a look through the page source, found `http:\/\/discidevflash-f.akamaihd.net\/i\/digmed\/dsc\/20151204\/149218.071.01.197_20151204_101536-,400k,110k,200k,600k,800k,1500k,3500k,5000k,.mp4.csmil\/master.m3u8`, and passed that unquoted to VLC for a great video. Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`youtube-dl` works for this site again. Considering it resolved.

Comment: Testing just now, I was able to command line curl the videos down in a console after discovering the url to the videos, but it seems the video files are really fragmented so you need to piece together like 10 files for a single show. maybe thats why youtube-dl was struggling with it in the first place. Also that one webpage was consuming about 1 gig of ram on my machine, so I stopped playing around with it...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to enable cross-site scripting. ick.

[image]

When I caved, at least, it worked...

[image]

Comment: -1 I already enabled it - Please read my list.

Comment: @l0b0 - yeah, i deserve that. it's probably then to do with the [widevine plugin module](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172366/52934) which comes w/ chrome but not chromium. at least, that should be the only difference. sorry about that.